# How to sync svn specific folder

Tags: svn, ubersvn

I'm trying to sync only the tag folder with another repository.
svnsync will sync entire repository. But i need only a specific folder
to be synced on post commit. I'm using uberSVN.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of SVN 1.5 you can use svnsync to mirror only parts of the repo.

See the [svnsync notes](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt) for instructions: typically `svnsync init file://pwd/dest http://svn.example.org/source/repos/project1` is all the changes you need.

Answer (score -1):

With turtoise svn I get in the folder I want to update and hit update. It will update only this folder and subdirectories recursively.

Comment: tag folder with another repository. svnsync